# How can I upload a local DB to Windows Azure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I develop a WebApi using a `LocalDB`, but I want to deploy it to Azure. I found out that you cant use a `LocalDB`, but you can use a `SQL Server Compact`.

Is there a way to migrate my old database including the `EDMX` and all the models to the `SQL Server Compact` or is there any other approach to upload the application to Azure?

Comment: Azure does not support SQL Server Compact, but you can use SQL Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure

Answer (score 0):

Do the same, but for MSQL, and after use your Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for your TSQL deployment on SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

> I found out that you cant use a LocalDB

We can connect to on-premises SQL Server from a WebApp in the Azure App Service using Hybrid connections. There are some snippet from the document. More detail info please refer to [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server).

> Hybrid Connections can connect Azure App Service Web Apps to on-premises resources that use a static TCP port. Supported resources include Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, HTTP Web APIs, App Service, and most custom Web Services.

As matze supplied [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure#publish-database-to-sql-azure) mentioned, we also can publish database to SQL Azure.